# (drupal) ckeditor breaks my blockcode tags

Tags: drupal, ckeditor, geshi

I'm using blockcode and geshi module on my [blog](http://tintifax.dyndns.org) to highlight syntax in my posts. but everytime i edit a post with blockcode tags i have to disable ckeditor, because otherwise it will break my code, it inserts nbsp and br tags, which are visible in the post, or totally drop newlines. this is really annoying.
does someone know a way how to fix this!?

thanks a lot!

Comment: This is sometimes a problem with plain page content too.  I ended up changing the default editor to be plain text to prevent tooltip text that was mostly `br` and `nbsp` garbage.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which module you are using to provide the ckeditor (ckeditor or wysiwyg module?), but the only thing I can think of would be to flat out prevent the editor from appearing for the specific field.  I wish there was a way to run a snippet and check for a substring, and then display the editor based on that... but that would be fairly complicated to do.

Answer (score 0):

The joy that is Drupal (notice the sarcasm) has a cleverer way to deal with this. I am using the CKEditor module.

Beneath every CKeditor WYSIWYG form field, you see the text:

CKEditor: the ID for excluding or including this element is {theme-name}:{path to field-name}

For one of my particular fields, specifically one that allows me to change the contents of a particular block, this becomes:

CKEditor: the ID for excluding or including this element is garland:admin/build/block/configure/block/10.edit-body

To *not* have CKEditor show up for this particular field, do this:

1. Go to your blocks administration page.
2. Find CKEditor.
3. Click on 'CKEditor' listed under the CKEditor block heading.
4. Figure out which is the relevant profile for you as an admin (probably by default this would be 'authenticated user').
5. Edit the relevant profile.
6. Click 'Visibility settings'.
7. "Use inclusion or exclusion mode:" is most probably set to "Exclusion". In the box labelled "Fields to exclude/include:" enter the line below the CKEditor box you want to get rid of. In my case "CKEditor: the ID for excluding or including this element is garland:admin/build/block/configure/block/10.edit-body"
8. Save

As the French say, "c'est tout".